# HTML entity for Ygrave?

Tags: html, html-entities

I have an xml file, the file contains ygrave, I want to know the html entity for the ygrave. I put `&Ygrave;` but the internet explorer shows error.

Comment: XML is not HTML so HTML entities cannot be used in XML (besides the minimal intersection of *amp*, *lt*, *gt*, and *quot*). Every other character has to be expressed using a numeric character reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no entity reference (to use the old SGML-based term) or named character reference (to use th HTML5 term) for y with grave accent, ỳ, Ỳ. Even the long list of [named character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references) in HTML5 CR does not contain such references.

Thus, you need to represent the characters ỳ and Ỳ as such or with (numeric) character references `&#x1ef3;` and `&#x1ef2;` (or their decimal counterparts `&#7923;` and `&#7922;`).

Note that in XML, you cannot use *any* entity references without defining them, except for the five [predefined entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent). The predefined entities of HTML are available in HTML documents only (including XHTML).

If you are copying data from an XML file into an HTML file, then there is no reason why you could not have ỳ and Ỳ copied as such – provided that the HTML file is UTF-8 encoded, as it should.